# How to Get data from an API every 2 min and use it in all of project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller, laravel-api

I want to build a website which need to get gold price every 3 min and use with this price in many of my  controller in my project.
how can get gold price from another API and how use this in my controller?

Comment: You have to use `setInterval` or `cron job`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cronjob to send a request to the gold api, receive the results and save them to the databse, and after 3 minute check if the price for the gold exists, update price. After you have the data you can access it from all your controllers and methods.

Laravel Cron jon - Read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)

Laravel HTTP Client - Read [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client)

This is all you need to know to finish your task